# Display unique values in combobox in Access 2010 Web App

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table which has 4 fields. One of them being "Material Name" and the other being "Temperature" where the entries in "Material Name" repeat a number of times. I am using that field as a source in a ComboBox of an Access web Form. But I am not able to display unique values. 
"DISTICNT" doesn't work in Access Web app, also there is no Group By and no VBA is to be used.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you displaying two fields in your combobox?

Comment: No. Only Material_Name field.